# Connecting to different servers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Scenario- We have more than 100 stores and each store has a server. I've created one application to install each users desktop. Their system needs to be connected with their store server, we have local database in place with the application which has procedures which will be interacting with the server. I can't hard code the server name in each procedures and in the SQL, Using DBLink didn't work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Configuration file/registry entry, deployed by group policy or other mechanism.

Comment: If you are at a store and use  sqlcmd -L from the command line  is only one server shown?

Comment: "What is the easy way to achieve this?" I don't know, but since you explicitly said "I can't hard code the server name in each procedures and in the SQL", that means it's not a programming question, so it should be moved to the most appropriate of: DBA or Server Fault or Super User.

Comment: Modified the question please check

Comment: Use linked servers. If using linked server didn't work, then fix it.

Comment: Joseph the principle of stack overflow is to ask questions and the community sees and benefits from the answers. Don't change the question after it has been answered. Ask separate questions

Comment: This question already had an accepted answer. If you have more questions, post a new one. You can find the text from the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to say some way to the Application installed ,which server to connect to..

there are many approaches...

1.Store connection details in a table from which the application can read to like below

```
storeid  connectionstring
1         somestring
```

So application at startup event,figure out which connection string to connect to..This approach would not require recompiling app and installing it everytime whenever store or connection string changes

2.In WebConfig,store connection details as key value pair like below..

```
<add key="storeid1" value="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
```

and then connect based on storeid,but this requires change in config file and app installation ,whenever a connection string or Storeid changes

Answer (score 2):

At login page/form in addition to Username and Password, add Server field.

Answer (score 1):

Your app can list any available sql servers on the network if there is only one then connect to it. If more than one put a dialog up to the users to confirm.

You can use:

```
sqlcmd -L
```

That will return any visible sql servers

Comment: Is it just me but the question I answered was different?